# Header of wav file

Tags: audio, wav

I wrote a program that read information from a .wav file . I received the following results.

```
chunkId            :RIFF
chunkSize          :13481688
format             :WAVE 
subchunk1ID        :fmt 
subchunk1Size      :16
Audioformat        :1
numberofchanels    :1
samplerate         :44100
Byterate           :88200
BlockAlign         :2
bitspersample      :16
subchunk2Id        :PAD 
subchunk2Size      :4044
```

The size of file is 13481696 .Normally, subchunk2Id is "data" and subchunk2Size=chunksize-36. This file run OK with audio player (Rhythmbox music player in Ubuntu). But I don't know why this format like that

Answer (score 0):

It's okay because the subchunk id is 'PAD'. A typical player is going to skip right past it to the 'data' chunk. 'PAD' chunks are often used to reserve space so that an 'INFO' can replace it in the future without having to move the 'data' chunk around.